# How to update all the values of a nested object in react or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, react-native, ecmascript-6

What is the appropriate way to update all the value of a nested dictionary.

Let's assume that I have this object:

```
someObj = {
  0: {
    message: 'Some text',
  },
  1: {
    message: 'Other text',
  },
}
```

If I just needed to update the first message on the object I would do something like:

```
someObj[0].message = 'New Message'
```

but what I want to achieve is to update all the message value in the object with one specific text.

What is the right way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `Object.keys()`, see from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, iterated in the same order that a normal loop would.

```js
const someObj = { 0: { message: 'Some text', }, 1: { message: 'Other text', },}

Object.keys(someObj)
      .forEach(e => {
         someObj[e].message = 'new_text'
      })

console.log(someObj)
```

**+1 out of scope update:**

There was an interesting question from @IsraGab in the comment section why to use this solution over `for..in`.

So I took a look at some benchmark to compare the speed of both of the solutions. Interestingly `Object.keys().forEach()` solution is usually **20%** more faster comparing with `for..in` in this scenario.

See the benchmark's result below:
[image: JS benchmark]

Run the comparison from here: https://jsbench.me/05khwctt9o

Comment: Why transforming to an array then run over the object while you can run over it using a `for in`?

Comment: @IsraGab It's a good question so I took a look at some benchmark to compare the speed of both of the solutions. Interestingly `Object.keys().forEach()` solution is usually **20%** more faster than `for..in`. See the result here: https://jsbench.me/05khwctt9o

Comment: @IsraGab Just extended my answer with that result, interesting conversation, thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for in loop`

```
    for(let prop in object){
       object[prop].message = 'Your string';
   }
```

```js
someObj = {
  0: {
    message: 'Some text',
  },
  1: {
    message: 'Other text',
  },
}

for(let prop in someObj){
someObj[prop].message = 'your string';
}

console.log(someObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const keys = Object.keys(someObj);
for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  someObj[keys[i]].message = 'Your string';
}
```